# Why is my handle button moving off the timeline on the right side?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm making a volume bar but for some reason, the slider button is appearing outside of the timeline. Instead, I'd like for it to appear on top of the progress bar.

// my volume bar component:

```
import React from 'react';

class AudioVolume extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      volume: 1,
      mute: false
    };

    this.handlePosition = this.handlePosition.bind(this);
    this.mouseMove = this.mouseMove.bind(this);
    this.mouseDown = this.mouseDown.bind(this);
    this.mouseUp = this.mouseUp.bind(this);
    this.mute = this.mute.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { volume } = this.props;

    this.setState({ volume });
    this.handle.style.width = this.timeline.offsetWidth + "px";
    this.handleCircle.style.marginLeft = this.timeline.offsetWidth + "px";
  }

  handlePosition(position) {
    let handleLeft = position - this.timeline.offsetLeft;

    if (handleLeft > this.timeline.offsetWidth || this.state.volume === 1) {
      this.handle.style.width = this.timeline.offsetWidth + "px";
      this.handleCircle.style.marginLeft = this.timeline.offsetWidth + "px";
    }

    if (handleLeft >= 0 && handleLeft <= this.timeline.offsetWidth) {
      this.handle.style.width = handleLeft + "px";
      this.handleCircle.style.marginLeft = handleLeft + "px";
    }

    if (handleLeft < 0) {
      this.handle.style.width = "0px";
      this.handleCircle.style.marginLeft = "0px";
    }
  }

  mouseMove(e) {
    this.handlePosition(e.pageX);
    this.setState({ mute: false });

    let volume = ((e.pageX - this.timeline.offsetLeft) / this.timeline.offsetWidth) * 1;

    if (volume >= 1) {
      volume = 1;
    } else if (volume <= 0) {
      volume = 0;
    }

    this.setState({ volume });
    this.props.receiveVolume(this.state.volume);
  }

  mouseDown(e) {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseUp);
  }

  mouseUp(e) {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseUp);
  }

  mute() {
    if (!this.state.mute) {
      this.setState({ mute: true });
      this.props.receiveVolume(0);
    } else {
      this.setState({ mute: false });
      this.props.receiveVolume(this.state.volume);
    }
  }

  render() {
    let volumeClass;

    if (this.state.volume >= 0.6) {
      volumeClass = "ap-volume-high";
    } else if (this.state.volume > 0) {
      volumeClass = "ap-volume-low";
    } else if (this.state.volume === 0) {
      volumeClass = "ap-volume-off";
    }

    if (this.state.mute) volumeClass = 'ap-volume-off';

    return (
      <div className="ap-volume-controls">
        <div className="ap-volume-icon"><i className={volumeClass}></i></div>

        <div id="ap-volume-timeline" onClick={this.mouseMove} ref={(timeline) => { this.timeline = timeline }}>
          <div id="ap-volume-handle" onMouseDown={this.mouseDown} ref={(handle) => { this.handle = handle }} />
          <div id="ap-volume-handle-circle" onMouseDown={this.mouseDown} ref={(handleCircle) => { this.handleCircle = handleCircle }} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AudioVolume;
```

// my volume bar CSS:

```
.ap-volume-controls {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 100px;
      margin-top: 25px;
      margin-left: 130px;

      .ap-volume-icon {
        margin-right: 10px;

        .ap-volume-high {
          content: image_url('audio_player/audio_volume_high.png');
          width: 17px;
          height: 14px;
        }

        .ap-volume-low {
          content: image_url('audio_player/audio_volume_low.png');
          width: 14px;
          height: 13px;
        }

        .ap-volume-off {
          content: image_url('audio_player/audio_volume_off.png');
          width: 17px;
          height: 13px;
        }
      }

      #ap-volume-timeline { 
        margin-top: 5px;
        width: 85px;
        height: 4px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        background: $audio-slider-gray;  

        #ap-volume-handle {
          width: 0;
          height: 4px;
          background: $green;
        }

        #ap-volume-handle-circle {
          width: 12px;
          height: 12px;
          border-radius: 50%;
          background: $white;
          margin-top: -8px;
        }
      }
    }
```

Here is what I mean:

[image]

How can I make the slider button appear on top of the progress bar rather than next to it?

And for clarity, the timeline is the gray bar, and the handle is the green bar:

[image]

Comment: Without a minimum example I can't be sure. But can you inspect the element and see what is there? I suggest you to take a better look at `<div id="ap-volume-handle-circle" onMouseDown={this.mouseDown} ref={(handleCircle) => { this.handleCircle = handleCircle }} />` positioning. Also inspect rest of the bar. If nothing is working try to create a working example, because like this is really hard to tell.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll give it a try!

Comment: I believe I've figured it out; I think it was the icon next to it (the padding/margins on the different images were messing up the volume timeline) However, the slider button seems to be appearing after the progress bar/outside of the timeline. I'll edit my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to the `#ap-volume-handle-circle{..` `margin-left: -6px;` should do the job.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a try!

Comment: Hm, it's still appearing next to the green progress bar. There's actually two different handle bars, let me add another picture to my post for clarity!

Comment: So just to clarify: your problem is that your white circle (`ap-volume-handle-circle`) is next to the green bar (`ap-volume-handle`) not at the very end of it. Right? And margin left: -6px to `#ap-volume-handle-circle` is not doing the job?

Comment: I actually just solved it! I had to make the position relative, and I used a variation of your solution (used left instead of margin-left)